# Error: Possible Loss Of Precision

Tags: double-precision

This is my code:

```
static int compoundBalance(double db, double dbTwo, double dbThree) {
if(dbThree == 0) return db;
return (1 + dbTwo)*compoundBalance(db, dbTwo, dbThree-1);
}
```

And I get these two errors. I'm not sure what to make of them. Any guidance? Thank you.

```
Factorial.java:60: error: possible loss of precision
    if(dbThree == 0) return db;
                            ^
  required: int
  found:    double

Factorial.java:61: error: possible loss of precision
    return (1 + dbTwo)*compoundBalance(db, dbTwo, dbThree-1);
                      ^
  required: int
  found:    double
2 errors
```

Comment: What is the point of doing all this double-precision arithmetic in `compoundBalance()` if the function only returns integer values? Did you mean to declare this function as `static double compoundBalance()` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature states that you're returning an int when you're actually returning a double. You can fix this by changing your signature to:

```
static double compoundBalance(double db, double dbTwo, double dbThree) {
```

This error is to stop you returning something like 6 when you meant to return 6.9. If you really want this behaviour, then instead of changing the signature you can cast the return value as an int.

```
static int compoundBalance(double db, double dbTwo, double dbThree) {
  if(dbThree == 0) return (int)db;
    return (int)((1 + dbTwo)*compoundBalance(db, dbTwo, dbThree-1));
  }
}
```